# Legend in FusionCharts (Pie chart) - PHP

Tags: javascript, php, charts, data-visualization, fusioncharts

Is it possible to display legend in PIE CHART (FUSIONCHARTS) - PHP ?

showLegend Attribute Name is active but not displaying !!!

[image: PIE CHART IMAGE]

`Chart Attribute Name:

caption='Vendor Wise Data Volume' startingAngle ='90' showLegend='1'  showPercentInToolTip='0' bgColor='f7f2ea'  chartTopMargin='20'   chartBottomMargin='20' formatNumberScale='0'  pieRadius='100'  exportEnabled='1' exportAtClient='1' exportHandler='index.php' labelDisplay='ROTATE'`

Comment: I don't know fusioncharts, I just found this: http://kb.fusioncharts.com/questions/398/How+can+I+display+legend+in+Pie+%26+Doughnut+charts%3F ; did you try it ?

Comment: Can you share your full data, chart dimensions and the version you are using. Are you using the PHP wrapper? If yes, try to render the chart normally (plain HTML. JS) without PHP, and see if it works. We can inspect only after you give enough data. As of now the `showLegend` attribute renders the legend at our side.

Comment: @zeflex yes I have read ... and using the same attribute mentioned above
showLegend='1' but no use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According To your problem, i have tried it out using the Chart [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fusioncharts/ZjyJT/) Of FusionCharts.

```
    FusionCharts.ready(function() {
    var ageGroupChart = new FusionCharts({
        type: 'pie3d',
        renderAt: 'chart-container',
        width: '450',
        height: '300',
        dataFormat: 'json',
        dataSource: {
            "chart": {
                "caption": "Vendor Wise Data Volume",
                "paletteColors": "#FFFF00, #6495ED",
                "bgColor": "#f7f2ea",
                "showBorder": "0",
                "use3DLighting": "0",
                "showShadow": "0",
                "enableSmartLabels": "0",
                "startingAngle": "0",
                "labelDisplay": "Rotate",
                "showPercentValues": "1",
                "showPercentInTooltip": "0",
                "pieRadius": "100",
                "exportEnabled": "1",
                "decimals": "1",
                "captionFontSize": "14",
                "subcaptionFontSize": "14",
                "subcaptionFontBold": "0",
                "toolTipColor": "#ffffff",
                "toolTipBorderThickness": "0",
                "toolTipBgColor": "#000000",
                "toolTipBgAlpha": "80",
                "toolTipBorderRadius": "2",
                "toolTipPadding": "5",
                "showHoverEffect": "1",
                "startingAngle": "90",
                "showLegend": "1",
                "legendBgColor": "#ffffff",
                "legendBorderAlpha": '0',
                "legendShadow": '0',
                "legendItemFontSize": '10',
                "legendItemFontColor": '#666666'
            },
            "data": [
                {
                    "label": "2015-04-21, 813,740.59",
                    "value": "813740.59"
            },
                {
                    "label": "2015-04-14, 6,580,863",
                    "value": "6580863"
            }
        ]
        }
    }).render();
});
```

Hope this will help you. For any further assistance @ [Chart Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fusioncharts/ZjyJT/)

Comment: Thanks for your support.